# How to map props in MapStateToProps?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, mapstatetoprops

I have tsx file who is returning this:

```
return (
<>
<Container>
data.map((item, i) => {
                let fullNameLetters = item.fullName.substring(0, 2);
                if (item.fullName.indexOf(' ') > 0) {
                  fullNameLetters = item.fullName.split(' ')[0][0].toUpperCase() + item.fullName.split(' ')[1][0].toUpperCase();
                }
                return (
                  <Card {...item} key={i} nameInitials={fullNameLetters} content={item.content} />
                );
              }) 
</Container>
</>
)
```

my MapStateToProps is this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: ApplicationState) => ({
  data: state.persons.data
});
```

So my question is how to put this code in mapStateToProps?:

```
data.map((item, i) => {
                let fullNameLetters = item.fullName.substring(0, 2);
                if (item.fullName.indexOf(' ') > 0) {
                  fullNameLetters = item.fullName.split(' ')[0][0].toUpperCase() + item.fullName.split(' ')[1][0].toUpperCase();
                }
```

Comment: Well, you can simply augment item with the `fullNameLetters` property `data: state.persons.data.msp(item=> ({...item, fullNameLetters})` But this doesn't make a lot of sense and also creates additional performance issues because mapStateToProps executes on every state change. So you would need to also add memoization. Explain why you want it in first place?

Comment: Because the data from persons dont have that prop fullNameLetters. But the card component have prop fullNameLetters.

Comment: You can extract it to a function and just call it `<Card {...item} nameInitials={getInitials(item)}`. You don't really need to store it in item because it is computable based on what you already have.

Comment: You may not need to do that as suggested by @YuryTarabanko. But if you need something similar for other use cases. You should check this: https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect